# Looking for a C# TDD framework?

Tags: c#, tdd

Is there a C# framework that allows you to follow TDD in a similar manner that RSpec works for Ruby and that would allow this:

```
obj.should_receive(a).with(b).and_return(c)
```

It seems to me that xUnit + Moq can be a good choice for TDD. What do you think about it?

Comment: i'm using Moq + nunit and its syntax is very similar to what you describe.

Comment: @sJhonny, then you should make that an answer, not a comment.

Comment: There's a **BDD** framework called *Story Q* which is kind of like that (http://storyq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: My 2 ct.: The way you write your test syntactically, does not influence what it does. Fluent style != TDD. You should prefer a well-known framework over a niche one that is fluent.

Comment: @usr Programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.

Answer (score 4):

http://nspec.org/

NSpec is more similar to RSpec. That's BDD, not TDD.

Comment: BDD and TDD are orthogonal concepts. One is a way of writing tests. The other describes how one integrates writing tests into one's workflow.

Comment: @Domenic someone says that BDD is TDD done the right way and I agree

Answer (score 2):

I use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) and [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/).  Add ing something like [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) or [StoryQ](http://storyq.codeplex.com/), and you should be well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into [Sharp Tests Ex](http://sharptestex.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to write assertions like this:

```
var c = mathObject.Add(5, 7);  
c.Should().Be.EqualTo(12);
```